# Creating user with Yocto works only partially

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, user-administration

I am trying to create a user to my system created using Yocto.

I have the following line in my recipe for my custom image:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " useradd -p 'myuser' -d /home/myuser --create-home myuser; "
```

The result is that I can't login as myuser, but I can change to myuser using su. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running this command on booted-up image works as expected?

Comment: It gives the same result as when run build-time.

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` requires some manual work. Write up done on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159878/cannot-login-to-newly-created-user-account).

Use [`adduser`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/adduser.8.html) instead.

Comment: Replacing useradd with adduser gives a build-time error about that line.

Comment: @TheAG Did you only replace the command or did you look into its syntax?

Comment: I first just replaced the command and the realized that I should have done a little more :) I then tested adduser in target system and noticed that it did what I wanted. The problem with it is that extrauser class in Yocto requires you to use useradd and not adduser.